# Rails 4: polymorphism, single-table inheritance, scoping...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose the following:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

Customers can be **red customers** and/or **blue customers**, but they are *never* just a customer. Red customers own dogs, blue customers wear hats (a customer *must* be hat-wearing or dog-owning). For a given order, red_customer is *never* equal to blue_customer. Since I never use customer_id, I want to eliminate it from my schema and replace it with red_customer_id and blue_customer_id. Each order has a red_customer_id and blue_customer_id.

Examples...

- @some_order.customer # no, bad, do not want
- @some_order.red_customer # returns a user object
- @some_order.blue_customer # returns a user object

Schema (currently ugly)

```
  create_table "orders"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_id" # I want to get rid of this
    t.integer  "red_customer_id"
    t.integer  "blue_customer_id"
  end
```

But if I remove user_id, then my associations break. How can I clean this up?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an order can only belong to a single user at a time I do not recommended to have 2 foreign_keys in your table. You can achieve the same result using Single Table Inheritance:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class RedCustomer < Customer
end

class BlueCustomer < Customer
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :red_customer, foreign_key: 'customer_id'
  belongs_to :blue_customer, foreign_key: 'customer_id'
end
```

This way you keep a single table for customers and a single foreign_key on orders.

For this to work you need a `type` string column in the customer table, also as the Order migration, add `polymorphic: true` to the customer foreign_key declaration, this way the column `customer_type` will also be created.

```
class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :customers do |t|
      t.string     :type
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.references :customer, polymorphic: true, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

It works as expected:

```
order = Order.create
order.red_customer = BlueCustomer.create #=> raises <ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch>
order.red_customer = RedCustomer.create #=> Ok
order.blue_customer #=> nil
order.red_customer #=> #<RedCustomer id: ...>
order.blue_customer = BlueCustomer.create #=> Ok
order.red_customer #=> nil
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful reply. Some questions...Customer.type can be 'red', 'blue' or 'both'...? Also, for some orders a customer is red, while on other orders the same customer is blue (see my dogs/hats illustration). This means type is dependent on order which seems a little confusing.

Comment: Oh I see, I din't understand that they could be both. Yeah it's a little confusing haha. I'll give it some thought and edit my answer

Comment: Appreciate your help. Someone offline suggested using "as:" (per the Rails guides on associations) but I'm still having trouble figuring out how to get rid of the redundant user_id.

Comment: I'm not sure how the 'as:' alias would help in this situation, but I'm having trouble thinking of a solution to this exact scenario. It seems to me that the type of the customer depends only the order? If so, shouldn't it be the case to have differente orders? Like red_order, blue_order? Just a guess. If everything fails, I would try to just keep track of the type of the customer by hand in the order table, with a column 'customer_type' that you set manually to 'Red', 'Blue' or 'Both'

Comment: The logic is something like this: some_order.red_customer = best_customer if best_customer.has_a_dog?; some_order.blue_customer = another_customer if another_customer.wears_a_hat?. Thanks for taking a look, I will keep poking around.